# PhysX Skeletal Animation

Tags: opengl, skeletal-animation, physx

I am developing a game and using OpenGL for graphics API and NVidia PhysX for the game's physics. Recently I implemented skeletal animation from [this](https://learnopengl.com/Guest-Articles/2020/Skeletal-Animation) site. The objects are read using assimp which retrieves the bone information from the model. The code from the above site is calculating one matrix per bone and passing this information to the vertex shader where it is transforming the vertices to the new positions. My question is how can I make the physics system follow the transformations from the model? A theoretical answer is also good for me. Thanks in advance

Edit:

Here is the code from the animator class, that can be found also in the link above, and in specific about the matrix calculation :

```
void CalculateBoneTransform(const AssimpNodeData* node, const glm::mat4& parentTransform)
{
    std::string nodeName = node->name;
    glm::mat4 nodeTransform = node->transformation;

    Bone* Bone = m_CurrentAnimation->FindBone(nodeName);

    if (Bone)
    {
        Bone->Update(m_CurrentTime);
        nodeTransform = Bone->GetLocalTransform();
    }

    glm::mat4 globalTransformation = parentTransform * nodeTransform;

    auto boneInfoMap = m_CurrentAnimation->GetBoneIDMap();
    if (boneInfoMap.find(nodeName) != boneInfoMap.end())
    {
        int index = boneInfoMap[nodeName].id;
        glm::mat4 offset = boneInfoMap[nodeName].offset;
        m_FinalBoneMatrices[index] = globalTransformation * offset;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < node->childrenCount; i++)
        CalculateBoneTransform(&node->children[i], globalTransformation);
}
```

And here is the Vertex Shader code that consumes the calculated matrices:

```
#version 330 core
#define NUM_CASCADES 3

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoords;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 aTangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 aBitangent;
layout(location = 10) in ivec4 boneIds; 
layout(location = 11) in vec4 weights;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 toShadowMapSpace[NUM_CASCADES];

const int MAX_BONES = 100;
const int MAX_BONE_INFLUENCE = 4;
uniform mat4 finalBonesMatrices[MAX_BONES];

out VS_OUT {
    vec3 FragPos;
    vec3 Normal;
    vec2 TexCoords;
    vec4 shadowCoords[NUM_CASCADES];
} vs_out;

void main()
{
    vec4 totalPosition = vec4(0.0f);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < MAX_BONE_INFLUENCE ; i++)
    {
        if(boneIds[i] == -1) 
            continue;
        if(boneIds[i] >=MAX_BONES) 
        {
            totalPosition = vec4(aPos,1.0f);
            break;
        }
        vec4 localPosition = finalBonesMatrices[boneIds[i]] * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
        totalPosition += localPosition * weights[i];
        vs_out.Normal = mat3(finalBonesMatrices[boneIds[i]]) * aNormal;
   }

    vec4 vsPos = model * totalPosition;
    gl_Position =  projection * view * vsPos;
    vs_out.TexCoords = aTexCoords;

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CASCADES; ++i)
    {
        vs_out.shadowCoords[i] = toShadowMapSpace[i] * vsPos;     
    }

    vs_out.FragPos = vec3(vsPos);
}
```

and here is the model calculation :

```
projection = Camera::GetInstance()->GetProjection();
model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
model = glm::translate(model, mPos); 
model = glm::scale(model, mScale);
```

Comment: Presumably you tried reading the position and rotation of each bone matrix and using it to position and orient a body with an appropriately-shaped collider? How have you attempted this so far and where specifically did you run into difficulty?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for the fast reply. What I've done so far is trying to use the transforms that are passed to the vertex shader (on my current model I have 32 bones and same amount of transforms) and applied that on top of the PhysX collider, but then the collider disappears from the screen. I also investigated a bit the transforms they look like they are in local space while I need a transform in world space...

Comment: So you multiplied them by an object space to world space matrix and got...? (I have to ask because you have not shown these steps and the specific inputs/outputs you get in the body of your question — you can edit it to fix that)

Comment: @DMGregory I have edited the question to add the corresponding code for the matrices calculations and the vertex shader code that consumes those matrices in order to move the vertices around. Any thoughts on those?